# Can I install a SSL cert only for webmail subdomain, but not whm/cpanel?

Tags: ssl, cpanel, whm

I want to install a certificate only for webmail subdomain, but not for cpanel, whm, calendar, and others subdomains included as it appears in the option given in WHM » Home »Service Configuration »Manage Service SSL Certificates.

Do you know how to do this separately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant use for only webmail but you can use for all at once when ever it will not work for https://webmail.domain.com it will work for only https://hostname/webmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, It's not possible to install it only for webmail services. cPanel is providing options to install SSL for all services (Calendar, cPanel, WebDisk, Webmail, and WHM ) at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to say that it wasn't necessary to buy a wildcard certificate , since i disabled the option Proxy Subdomains , in WHM's "Tweak settings" section , and then, all requests to XXXX.domain.com I redirected to domain.com/XXXX setting up each subdomain from cPanel subdomain section.

Thanks anyway for your help :)